# Nested model parameters during an HTML post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, curl

I'm been playing with calling my rails controller using an HTTP POST.  I can get it to work with a curl command such as this, given a model named item and an attribute in that item called name:

```
curl -X POST -d "<item><name>myname</name></item>" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:3000/items.xml
```

What I'm curious about is how to make the same call using text instead of xml as my content type....  I tried:

```
curl -X POST -d "name=myname" http://localhost:3000/items.xml
```

but that seems to pass the 'name' parameter as the top level scope; so it doesn't end up in my params in the controller....

I'm a noob at this; just want to understand how to do it both ways....

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer, you need to

(a) send it as -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

(b) specify the parameters as Object[field]=value - for example User[name] would refer to the name field in some user object.

(c) [Not Required because you use curl] encode the parameters and POST/PUT them.

#### Encoding the parameters

The encoding is simple enough and although curl will do it for you, it's useful to understand it. I've quoted an extract from the W3C spec...
"

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:

1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').
2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by`&'.

"

#### Simple Example (New User Form)

The example below is how to send a simple "New User" form.

If I have fields in the user object for name, password, email etc, I specify them like this ...

```
user[firstname]=chris&user[login]=cmccauley&user[company_id]=8&user[email]=&user[surname]=mccauley
```

then curl will escape them to give ...

```
user%5Bfirstname%5D=chris&user%5Blogin%5D=cmccauley&user%5Bcompany_id%5D=8&user%5Bemail%5D=&user%5Bsurname%5D=mccauley
```

... before posting them like this extract from a wire dump ...

#### Wireshark dump

```
POST /users/19 HTTP/1.1    
Host: localhost:3000    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042523 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.10    
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5    
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate    
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7    
Keep-Alive: 300    
Connection: keep-alive    
Referer: http://localhost:3000/users/19/edit

Cookie: _my_session=048d330143de668e027c8cd52654e8c5

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 259



user%5Bfirstname%5D=chris&user%5Blogin%5D=cmccauley&user%5Bcompany_id%5D=8&user%5Bemail%5D=&user%5Bsurname%5D=mccauley&user_password=********&user%5Bjob_id%5D=14&user%5Bpassword%5D=dd793a64b74e108fcdc5d809040e24afcc21ad2c&authenticity_token=&id=19&_method=PUT
```

Answer (score 2):

"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is already default with curl -d, no need for anything extra

-X POST is superfluous, as -d implies POST

-d does *not* URL encode the data. To get curl to do that for you, you need to use --data-urlencode instead