# Mongoose and Form submission with sub-group

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

so, i have a Mongoose Schema, something like:

```
Person: {
   name: String,
   address: {
      street: String,
      number: String,
      city: String
   }
}
```

Is there a way, to code our form so that i can map directly from req.body to the Person instance? considering the sub-division in address.
I tried:

```
<form>
   <input name="name">
   <input name="address.street">
   <input name="address.number">
   <input name="address.city">
</form>
```

and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form>
    <input name="name">
    <input name="address[street]">
    <input name="address[number]">
    <input name="address[city]">
</form>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950133/nested-model-parameters-during-an-html-post) on application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding.